# IPA file is not working when installed by Ad-Hoc

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution, visual-studio-app-center

I'm looking to get our first revision of our mobile app on App Center for our QA team and I'm getting stuck on the iOS deployment.

I've [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support) this and [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/itunesmetadata) that and [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ad-hoc-distribution) this and no matter what my app is not installing correctly on my phone.

when appcenter installs the app on my iphone I see it trying to install it and an app is there (even though its not picking up my icon for some reason) and clicking on the app does nothing.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at all. I made the proper certs and stuff on the developer portal and added my device to both the appcenter website and to my apple developer portal so at this point I'm at a lost on what I'm doing wrong.

any sort of clarity would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: so looking at the logs I get the following message:

> Unable to perform action "Promote" on com.mydomain.demoapp because is it not currently supported
>
> All action attempts failed for placeholder: com.mydomain.demoapp

I have no idea what that means hope someone can tell me.

Comment: have you looked at the device logs?

Comment: no, not really sure how to do that to be honest

Comment: use XCode - https://www.appdome.com/no-code-mobile-integration-knowledge-base/obtaining-ios-device-logs/

Comment: will that work with xamarin though?

Comment: it has nothing to do with Xamarin.  You're trying to figure out why an IPA won't install on the device - so a good first step is to check the device logs to see if there are any meaningful messages.  Alternately, try installing directly from the IDE to see if you get an error.

Comment: I checked the device log, which there weren't any but trying to install the app from the phone connected to the usb gave me some better error messages to steer me in the right direction

Comment: updated my question to reflect what I found in my device log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out my problem, I had a bad entitlements.plist entry and that was throwing off the install, removed it and it worked.

Comment: Which entry? I am stuck on the same issue.

Comment: it's been so long, I don't actually remember now, think it was the wifi entitlement, the best thing you can do is look at what entitlement is setup on your apple developer listing and then see what doesn't line up with your entitlement.plist file, that's what I did to fix my problem.

Comment: Figured it out. It was that push notification was enabled in apple Dev center but not fully configured...missing the push cert...so apple treats it as disabled